# rqt_plot cannot receive any data

Tags: plot, rqt

I tried to plot my data into `rqt_plot` to get the figure. However `rqt` suddenly return zeros for all of my data.

I checked the data by using `rostopic echo` command and it actually has non-zero data stream. I created a node that only had one publisher publishing a non-zero number but also got zero plot. I also tried to reinstall this `ros-kinetic-rqt` but still not working.

Could someone help?

[image]